# Scipy.spatial.distance.pdist gives RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix, runtime-error

I have a 16000 X 600 boolean matrix. I want to create a distance matrix from it using Jaccard Distance as the metric. The final matrix would be of dimensions would be 16000 X 16000. For this I used [scipy.spatial.distance.pdist](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html).

When I run my program after some time the program throws this warning but does not exit

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py:386: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
return (np.double(np.bitwise_and((u != v), np.bitwise_or(u != 0, v != 0)).sum()) / np.double(np.bitwise_or(u != 0, v != 0).sum()))
```

and no further output is there even after the program is left to run for some more time.

How can rectify this issue?

Other details:

- The matrix has high sparsity (~99%).
- 115 rows contain only 0's.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have two issues:

1. Your matrix is large and sparse, so try using a sparse representation:

   ```
   import scipy.sparse
   # assuming your big boolean matrix is called A
   sA = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(A)
   ```
2. Any pair of rows with all zeros (in both rows) will produce `NaN` values. This is what's triggering the warning.

The reason your code never exits is that the matrix is simply too big. Unfortunately, Scipy's distance function don't support sparse matrices, so you'll have to write the Jaccard distance yourself. (See [scipy's dense implementation here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L372).)

Comment: I have eliminated all zero rows from my data. I even applied CSR representation. I am basically confused between converting it to a Compresses Sparse Row form or should I use `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(A).todense()` to get a dense representation?

Comment: The code in your comment should just reproduce A, which isn't what you want. Now that you've removed your zero rows, what happens when you run your original code (no sparse matrices)?